# Cronjob, every 20 minutes. Starting direct after reboot

Tags: cron

running a cronjob like

```
*/15 * * * * sh /home/me/skript.sh  >> /home/me/out.log 2>&1
```

will execute the `skript.sh` every 15 minutes. Starting the computer at 12:10, I have to wait 5 minutes.

Is there a way to get the cronjob starting immediately after reboot and then every 15 minutes?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: You could add a new `@reboot` job and and use `flock -n` in your script to make sure that only one instance is running at a time.

Comment: Not from cron. What you need is a service, start that service during booting and then save current time in a temp file where you read that temp file and execute the core of the script every time the time in the file - 15 minutes is now.

Comment: Or a boot service that updates a file in /etc/cron.d with custom times. Either way, you must learn how to use Services, or you won't be able to maintain it.

Comment: You could start your script with `@reboot`, then early in the script: `echo "scriptname parameters " | at now + 15 minutes`.

Answer (score 2):

### systemd to the rescue

This is not possible with `cron` but `systemd` can do that.
You need to create two systemd units, one that starts your script, and one for the timer.

file `/etc/systemd/system/my-fifteen-minutes.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=15 minute timer

[Timer]
# start this 0 minutes after boot:
OnBootSec=0 min

# ... and then every 15 minutes:
OnActiveSec=15 min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

file `/etc/systemd/system/my-fifteen-minutes.service` (note the different extension):

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/home/me/skript.sh >> /home/me/out.log 2>&1"
User=me
```

Put these files in the directory `/etc/systemd/system` and enable the timer with

```
# make systemd aware of them
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# make sure the timer is engaged at startup
sudo systemctl enable my-fifteen-minutes.timer

# start the timer "now" (without rebooting):
sudo systemctl start my-fifteen-minutes.timer

# examine the status:
systemctl status my-fifteen-minutes.timer my-fifteen-minutes.service
```

The command `systemctl status my-fifteen-minutes.timer` will show something like

```
● my-fifteen-minutes.timer - 15 minute timer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-fifteen-minutes.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2018-07-01 14:42:05 CEST; 1s ago
  Trigger: Sun 2018-07-01 14:57:05 CEST; 14min left

Jul 01 14:42:05 stratum9 systemd[1]: Started 15 minute timer.
```

This means: The *timer* was triggered `1s ago` and will be triggered again in ~14 minutes (at "Sun 2018-07-01 14:57:05 CEST").

Note that the *timer* and the *service* are two different things, and you need to define both. By default, a *timer unit* starts a *service unit* with the same name (except for the extension `.timer` vs. `service`), i.e. `foo.timer` would control `foo.service` (you can override that, though). The *timer unit* just defines *when* something happens to the *service unit*, and the *service unit* defines the actual action (in your case: start the script `/home/me/skript.sh`).

---

Further reading:

- timers: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html
- services: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
- units (applies to both timers and services): https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html