# How do I properly install a systemd timer and service?

Tags: systemd

I am attempting to create and install on Bionic a custom pair of systemd timer & service units for running a command periodically.  I know that the files should be placed in `/etc/systemd/system` and then I should run `systemctl daemon-reload`, but I'm not clear on whether I need to enable or start anything in order for the timer to be fully installed and "running," and the few articles I can find that address this point all give different information.

My `.timer` file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run custom command periodically

[Timer]
Unit=my-custom-command.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 0/8:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

My `.service` file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run a custom command
OnFailure=mail-systemd-failure@%n.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/custom-command
User=dedicated-user
Group=dedicated-user
```

The conflicting articles I've read are:

- [This article](https://medium.com/horrible-hacks/using-systemd-as-a-better-cron-a4023eea996d) says to run:

  ```
  systemctl daemon-reload
  systemctl enable $NAME.timer
  systemctl start $NAME
  ```

  As I understand it, the latter command is the same as `systemctl start $NAME.service`, which I would expect to immediately run the command defined by the service, which is not what I want to do.
- [This gist](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/350238961f451d6946dd) says to just run:

  ```
  systemctl daemon-reload
  systemctl start $NAME.timer
  ```
- [This article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-systemd-timers-as-cron-replacement/) says to run:

  ```
  systemctl enable $NAME.timer
  systemctl start $NAME.timer
  ```

So do I enable and/or start the timer (or its service?), and what exactly is the difference between the two?  Do the commands I need to run change depending on whether the unit files are newly installed or being reloaded after an edit?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To run a unit at specified times or intervals you need *two* units:

- a *service unit* that defines *what* to run
- a *timer unit* that defines *when* to run the *service unit*

By convention, the timer unit starts another unit with the same name, 
i.e. `foo.timer` starts `foo.service`. You can override this by defining
the `Unit=other.service` attribute in the timer unit (like you did).

If both unit files are created and put in `/etc/systemd/system` you need
to make `systemd` aware of them by issuing

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This makes `systemd` reload all unit files and re-consider their dependencies
because `systemd` *caches* these files somehow. So whenever you change a unit
file, this command is required.

After that you need to *enable* the *timer unit*:

```
systemctl enable foo.timer
```

This commands simply enables auto-start at boot time (but doesn't start the unit yet).
Do *not* enable the service unit because that would mean to start the *service* at
boot time (independent of any timer settings).

Now the next time you boot, the timer will be engaged. To start it immediately
(without booting) you would run

```
systemctl start foo.timer
```

From now on, the timer unit will start the service unit whenever the time comes.
You can combine *enabling* and *starting* with

```
systemctl enable --now foo.timer
```

You can (and should) leave the service unit alone, i.e. neither *enable* nor *start* it.
This is now handled by the timer unit.

To see the current status of both timer and service, issue

```
systemctl status foo.timer foo.service
```

#### To summarize

- `systemctl enable/disable` controls the behaviour when booting
- `systemctl start/stop` controls the behaviour right now
- `enable` does *not* imply `start` (neither does `disable` imply `stop`).
  This can be overriden with the `--now` switch.
- only `enable` and `start` the timer unit, not the service unit
- issue `systemctl daemon-reload` whenever you edit the unit files

---

Further reading:

- timers: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html
- services: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
- units (applies to both timers and services): https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html
- a [related post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051208/504066)