# How to start and stop a systemd service on a timer?

Tags: systemd

While it's relatively straightforward to setup `systemd` to start a service at a particular time, how can I also make it stop at a different time?

The idea would be to run a service overnight only, and stop it in the morning.

Comment: There is some reason for avoiding the use of crontab?

Comment: @AlessandroCarini there could be several reasons. `systemd` timers have a more flexible configuration than crontab. And this is a perfectly valid question about `systemd`, so no reason to make it about crontab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, that a `systemd` timer is designed in a way so that it *starts* a service at a specific time. So to make it stop a service, it's necessary to make a workaround.

Luckily, there are several ways to achieve this.

###### Option 1: Make Service A conflict with Service B

The first option is to create a `oneshot` Service B that is in conflict with Service A. The advantage of this method is that it relies solely on `systemd` unit files, but the disadvantage is that you have to modify Service A (or create drop-in configuration).

First, you need to modify the configuration of Service A, so it conflicts with Service B:

Add this the configuration of A.service:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=B.service
...
```

Then create a B.service that does nothing:

```
[Unit]
Description=B service description

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo ''
```

*This method is taken from [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395231/406012).*

###### Option 2: Make Service B simply stop Service A

Another option is to create a `oneshot` Service B that simply runs the command to stop Service A. The advantage of this method is that you *don't* have to modify Service A, but the disadvantage is that it relies on running `systemctl` and not solely on `systemd` unit files.

For this method, you only need to create a B.service, but this time it will run a command:

```
[Unit]
Description=B service description

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl stop A.service
```

For both options, you then create a different timer for each of those services. Timer A will now start Service A, and Timer B will later start Service B - effectively stopping Service A.

See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083537/how-do-i-properly-install-a-systemd-timer-and-service) for more information about setting up `systemd` services and timers.

Comment: For completeness: [`RuntimeMaxSec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RuntimeMaxSec=) might be set although will report the service as `failed`  after termination, but that can only be cosmetic in most cases ... And if that service is used to run a script, then some logic can be implemented within the script to end both as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've set this up and it looks like it should work. Meanwhile I've also put a [feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/28684) with systemd to simplify this.